# tabs icon deteriorated while scrolling in android

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

I am using phonegap to build android app. The problem right now I am facing is that when I scroll down in listview the tabs icon's border at the bottom becomes rough and deteriorated. Could someone help me out why this is happening and how to solve it? I am adding all the images using css.

**Update**

Here is my code

css

```
footer {
position:fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
bottom:0; 
left:0;
padding: 0;
line-height: 100px;
z-index:2;
background: url(../../assets/img/tabbg.png) repeat-x;
}
footer ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0; padding: 0;
text-align: center;
}
footer ul li {
display: block;
float: left;
width: 33%; line-height: 50px;
margin-right: 0.5%;
height: 58px;
text-align: center;
overflow: hidden;
}
footer ul li.one { 
margin-left: 0.5%; 
}
footer ul li a {
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 1px;
height: 100%; width: 100%;
}
footer ul li a.home { 
background: url(../../assets/img/home3.png) center no-repeat; 
}
footer ul li a.profile { 
background: url(../../assets/img/camera2.png) center no-repeat; 
}
footer ul li a.cam { 
background: url(../../assets/img/profile2.png) center no-repeat; 
}
```

Here is my html for tabs

```
<footer>
    <ul>
        <li class="one"><a href="#" rel="home" class="home tabs"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="camera" class="profile tabs"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="profile" class="cam tabs"></a></li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```

Comment: Could you post a visual aid like a screenshot and/or some example code?

Comment: Can someone help me out? Does someone else is experiencing the same problem in their phonegap apps

Comment: I am still waiting for help...

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing exactly the issue you're getting it's difficult to know if it's this however I'm having problems porting an App I built for the iPhone in PhoneGap to Android (still using PhoneGap).

I'm finding that using position Fixed causes issues and I've also had problems using width:100% (trying to cater for any-width phone) as opposed to a specific pixel value.  Using overflow:hidden on whole-page divs also seems to be flaky.

I was getting display issues where elements would disappear and reappear.  I'm still having problems using css rotate.

Using position:absolute and setting page-size div dimensions using window.innerWidth and innerHeight seems to cure things.

A bit non-specific I'm afraid but it may help..

Answer (score 1):

I'd missed off the target-densityDpi field from the viewport metatag which appears to be crucial.

Leaving it out means the phone scales down everything by a factor of 1.5 I'm confused as to why unless background graphics dimensions cause this behaviour.  I noticed window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight were reporting 320*533 instead of the actual 480x800 screen size.

While it looked fine I suspect the effort of scaling everything was taking too many resources - I was getting draw timeouts in LogCat - and I guess this caused the dropouts and flicker.

The scaling is also causing the rough edges. When static the phone anti-aisled the edges but when you drag an element its edges became pixelated.